# Add new object to collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model Group with a has_many relationship to User. In my code, I want to add a new user to a group.

I tried

```
newUserID = 1
@group.users.build(:id => newUserID)
@group.save
```

but I get an error that users is invalid:

```
#<ActiveRecord::Errors:0x7f69224f8cc8 @errors=#<OrderedHash {"users"=>[#<ActiveRecord::Error:0x7f69224257b0 @attribute=:users, @options={}, @message=:invalid, @base=#<Group id: nil, group_id: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>, @type=:invalid>
```

In this particular case I should point out that this particularly group does not exist yet but should be created at the time of calling save as well.

I tried googling but was not able to find anything useful (probably because hundreds of pages with content not relating specifically to this come in my way :-( )

Answer (score 4):

```
@group.users << User.create(:attr => 'value',...) # Create a new User and add it to the group (Id will be assigned automaticly)
@group.users << User.find(user_id) # Add an existing user to the association
```

Im pretty sure its not a problem to add a user to a group which doesnt have an id yet, ruby can deal with this.

Comment: That does something different than the OPs code, though. I agree with what you're saying, but *how* you add a user matters.

Comment: Actually the second line looks interesting. (My wording may have been misleading, by "adding a NEW user" I did not mean a newly created user object, just an existing user that is new to the group.)

Answer (score 3):

You should save the group first:

```
@group.save
@group.users.create(:id => newUserID) # this creates & saves your user
```